# Swift: Execute Bash command with international formatted Strings

Tags: swift, bash, applescript

I have problems executing commands from **Applescript** and now with **Swift**.
It is necessary to launch the commands with "/bin/bash" and the arguments -c or -lc. The problem is that being from Spain, commands can include accents.
The different accents as á, é, í ..etc, cuts the command and concludes with errors.
Example command like:

```sh
mkvmerge -i Poesía bonita.mkv
```

will launched as:

```sh
mkvmerge -i Poesi
```

Tried with simple quotes and double quotes but didn't work.

```sh
mkvmerge -i "Poesía bonita.mkv"
```

```sh
mkvmerge -i 'Poesía bonita.mkv'
```

Is there a correct way to launch the command from Swift?

I use:

```swift
let command = "mkvmerge - i '/Users/Poesía bonita.mkv'"

let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-lc", command]        
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()
```

Just tried @RobC solution escaping the special characters with this function:

```swift
func repairString(theString: String) -> String{

    let accentedChars = ["á","Á","ä","Ä","é","É","í","Í","ó","Ó","ö","Ö","ú","Ú","ü","Ü","ñ","Ñ"]

    var theNewString = ""
    for char in accentedChars{
        if theString.contains(String(char)) {
            theNewString = theString.replacingOccurrences(of: String(char), with: "\\" + String(char))
        }
    }

    return theNewString
}
```

But does not work

```sh
Error: The file '/Users/Poes\i' could not be opened for reading: open file error.
```

Has someone another idea?

Regards and thanks

Comment: How exactly do you set `command` in the Swift code? The two quoted examples you show are exactly right for commands entered at the shell prompt.

Comment: When executing shell commands via Applescript's `do shell script` command you'll need to escape the accented characters prior to passing to the shell -  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535221/how-to-grep-umlauts-and-other-accented-text-characters-via-applescript/49556783#49556783)  it includes a subroutine called `escapeChars` that should help.

Comment: _you'll need to escape the accented characters prior to passing to the shell_ **Really!!** I have done a lot of scripts with Applescript and until High Sierra, it was not necessary, or am I wrong?

Comment: I thought that with Swift it would not be so messy to create a script or application where only calls to the command line are made. **Thanks for the advise**

Comment: Does escaping with a single backslash make any difference, i.e. `with: "\"`

Comment: No, it's the same result: Error: The file '/Users/Poes\i' thanks anyway @RobC

Comment: I have an Python script to export the mkvmerge JSON output and when I execute this Python script form the Swift app, the output as JSON is cutted at the first accented character. Just crazy!! It's really hard to do anything from the command line.

Comment: “It is necessary to launch the commands with "/bin/bash"”—Why? This should be sufficient: `task.launchPath = "/path/to/mkvmerge"; task.arguments = ["- i", "/Users/Poesía bonita.mkv"]`. Does `mkvmerge -i 'Poesía bonita.mkv' ` work when run directly in Terminal? Run `env` and check that LANG is UTF-8. Accented characters should not break anything, not unless it’s ASCII (which it shouldn’t be).

Comment: I just tried like @foo suggested: `task.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/mkvmerge"; task.arguments = command` being command `let command = ["-i", thePath.path]` and the result is once again: `Error: The file '/Users/Poes\i'  could not be opened...`. The _env_ is the correct _LANG=es_ES.UTF-8_. It works perfect when run directly in Terminal. It's very weird!

Comment: **I just tried a crazy thing and it worked!** I made a **bash script** ho launches the other Python script: `theScript="$1"\ntheFile="$2"\nexport LANG=es_ES.UTF-8\n python $theScript "$theFile"` the trick is surely the line `export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8`. Is there a way to launch this line or `env` from Swift?

Comment: Use `Process.environment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a solution:

```swift
let launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/python"
let arguments = [PyPath.path, correctPath.path]

print(shell(launchPath, arguments))


func shell(_ launchPath: String,_ arguments: [String]) -> String {

    let task = Process()
    task.environment = ["LANG" : "es_ES.UTF-8"]
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments = arguments
    task.waitUntilExit()

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    return output
}
```

The trick was to set the environment variable "LANG" to the correct one. 
It seems that Process() sets its env as default to create the task.

The same will be necessary in Applescript.

Thanks to @RobC and @foo
*I will never stop learning from the best ones.* ;)